# Wordpress woocommerce 2nd and 3rd product image blurry

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, customization

i have WordPress woocommerce store, only three product in store,
but issue is first product image complete show height and width, and product 2nd and 3rd image size is stretch. so how i can display proper image and 2nd and 3rd.

2nd original product uploaded Image link [2nd product image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edVAW.jpg)  And 3rd original product uploaded Image link [3rd product image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DX33d.jpg)

but product view are different

Product page link :[Product Link](http://bilingualnews.jp/?post_type=product)

Answer (score 1):

Remove width 680px and height 800px from this class "ul.products.list li.product img"

Comment: I have remove that css but no effect 
please any suggestion.

Comment: 1st image complete view but 2nd and 3rd image are cut

Comment: You have uploaded original image but wp cropped your image 300*300px so please use original image

Comment: yes but i have original image uploaded 
then upload finish so by default   image crop 300*300px , how to remove 300*300px by default ?

Comment: I can see that products on your page are designed to show in columns and they are forced to show one below other. Do you want to show them one below other only?

Comment: Please have a look this url https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/ I think some help this url

Comment: @SimrandeepSingh Yes .

Comment: then you need to change your thumbnail size as the width and height of your product list is more than the defined thumbnail size. You can read [this link](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/set-woocommerce-image-dimensions-upon-theme-activation/) to change thumbnail size.

Comment: You need to put it in your functions.php file